# Finger the digit

Tags: lateral-thinking, alphametic

Officials acquired two anonymized self texts
by the `G` Gang member known as `i`,
and hope these will help you identify the boss, `B`.

> $\kern166mu$     `G`   `=`   `i` `N` `t` `E` `r` `M` `s` `O` `f` `G`
>   
>   $\kern199mu$ `.` `G`   `=`   `i`   `/`   `B` `.` `i`

Investigators have thus far determined that each gangster
(`i`, `N`, `t`, `E`, `r`, `M`, `s`, `O`, `f` and `B`)
must secretly be one of the foremost citizens of Whollywood
(`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` or `9`)
and that foul mathplay is surely afoot.

Just which digit do you finger as `B`?

<sub>(
No leading zeros in Whollywood.
  `G` is not an 11th digit.
    `=`, `.` and `/` are not in disguise.
)</sub>

Comment: Wait... so G is the last few digits of itself?

Comment: Not a typo, `G` is defined in terms of itself (and is not an 11th digit)

Comment: Probably G should be some sort of expression starting with digit(s) to match all places where it is.

Comment: Just to be clear:  Every letter except `G` represents one of the digits from 0 to 9?  The `=`, `.`, and `/` represent equality, a decimal point and division, respectively?

Comment: That the symbols represent themselves is now included in the puzzle statement

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The boss `B` is

> 8

Since `G` is defined in terms of itself, it stands to reason that

> G is an infinitely repeating sequence of digits

Since `B` is missing from `G`, we can figure that `.G` is

> $.G = 1 / 8.1 =\ .\overline{123456790}$
>  
>  (Could be figured out via fractions of repeated 9s, as in:
>      `1/9=.111...`,
>    `12/99=.121212...`,
>  `475/999=.475475475...`,
>  `iNtErMsOf/999999999 = .iNtErMsOf iNtErMsOf iNtErMsOf ...`.
>  The divisors of 999999999 are easy because it is so divisible by 3:
>  999999999=3×3×3×3×12345679.)

and `G` is then

> $\overline{123456790}$

Comment: Very clever!  I was wondering if `G` could be $\infty$, but I didn't see how $.\infty$ made any sense.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daro6K6mym8) may be of interest to readers.