# Troll Addition 1 + 1 + 1 or 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

Tags: riddle, mathematics, lateral-thinking

> **What do you get if you add 1 to 1 three times?**

Note the tags for this problem are mathematics and lateral thinking...hmm

*Oh yeah, and btw, the question title is kinda misleading...*

Comment: that new edit kinda changed the meaning of the last phrase

Comment: [This question is insane](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/unknown_133991)

Comment: @frarugi87 I like how the linked website states it twice

Comment: --- removed ---

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As lateral thinking so:

> Answer is: 2, doesn't matter how many times we add 1 to 1 result is always 2:P

Comment: Ack, you beat me by seconds!

Comment: That means we got same thinking:P lateral:)

Comment: @phylyp this has got to be the fastest question answered on record :P

Comment: @phylyp lowkey refreshed the page and got two new answers

Comment: I propose "2 2 2" as the answer. :-)

Comment: @NL628 Not faster than [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/9384/40853), though. **50 seconds** (including scrolling and clicking and typing time). Wow!

Answer (score 23):

That would be:

> 2, three times, wouldn't it?

Rationale:

> The specific action is adding 1 to 1. Its not cumulatively adding 1.

Comment: I just looked through your profile and I realized that you got 250 points from my Troll Addition question and 160 points from my "Harrier Side of me one" wow :O

Answer (score 10):

I get...

> ... **7**.

Could be...

> ... 1+1+1 = 3 (base 10) = **11** (base 2).

OR could be...

> ... 1+1+1+1 = 4 (base 10) = **100** (base 2).

And...

> ... **11** [or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) **100** = 111 (base 2)
>  
>       
>  = 7   (base 10)

Comment: the troller the answer the better :) have a look at the other answers for fun

Comment: Already had, just couldn't resist. Probably should've saved this solution for a puzzle of its own.

Comment: [and another] Congratulations on being hot! My hottest was ["Finger that bad digit"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31297/finger-the-digit) until I changed its title. I hope your suspension is short, @NL628, you'll be fun live. And thank for whiskering a place to not go. Bye for now.

Comment: i like how Finger that bad digit is now a linked question ;)

Answer (score 10):

Come on guys, it's obviously

> 1111

Answer (score 8):

The other answers seem more reasonable, but the programmer in me just instantly thought of this:

> "What do you get if you add 1 to 1 three times?"
> Read aloud: "add 1 2 1 3 times"
> That is a function that looks like this:
>  `f = (+1213)*`, i.e. a function that takes some input number n and returns a new function that would add `n*1213` to its own input number.
> So that new function is what I get if I "add 1 to 1 three times"

Answer (score 7):

If you read it out phonetically...

> ...you can get **363**

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised this hasn't been said so far:

> Answer is: 1 + 1×3 = 2

Comment: isn't that 4? idk

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Read the title of the question again

Comment: no but `1+1*3` evaluates to 4. If you're doing `1+1` 3 times, then sorry but that _has_ been said already (see accepted answer).

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Let me rephrase: troll question => troll answer :P

Answer (score 6):

This is my take:

> The trolls of Terry Pratchett's discworld count "one, two, many". Then they continue with "many-one, many-two, many-many, many-many-one" and so on. So I'm going to say "many-one", as 1+1+1+1 is clearly the interpretation of "adding 1 to 1 three times".

Answer (score 5):

Is it:

> 11, using concatenation

?

Comment: > add 1 to 1 **three times**

Comment: you get 11 each time!

Comment: oh, I see now where you're coming from :)

Comment: String concatenation, funny. Happens so often.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> **5**

because

> given that the question was tagged with [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics) it is clearly referencing one of the most popular online mathematics references: [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences®](https://oeis.org) and as most mathematicians know the first three elements in the sequence with the index "1 to [sic] 1" (aka [A000121](https://oeis.org/A000121)) are 1, 2, and 2. Adding these up yields 5.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little surprised no one mentioned:

> 112

because

> 1 added to (one three times) 111 = 112

Similarly, it could be

> 4

because

> 1 + (1 + 1 + 1) or 1 + (1 * 3), with each term in parentheses being "one three times"

Answer (score 2):

(Add one to one) three times
so (1+1)x3=6